# pyside qapplication exec with while loop

Tags: python, qt, loops, pyside

Basically I have a program that will create a basic hello world program in PySide qt framework. The difference is that it does `print("loop")` in a while loop before `exec_()` is called. The problem with that the loop won't finish until the user is done with the program, so it will only call `exec_()` when the loop's done.

My problem is that if you run it like this, `print("loop")` will run, but the window won't respond, and doesn't display "Hello, loop!"). If you indent `qt_app.exec_()` under `while running:`, then the window will respond, but `print("loop")` only executes once before closing the window, and executes only once after closing it.

I need to be able to have the main window be responding while its printing "loop" to the console multiple times.

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel('Hello, loop!')
label.show()

running = True #only set to False when user is done with app in the real code.

while running:

  #I am handling connections here that MUST be in continual while loop
  print("loop")

qt_app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a GUI application you have to let the GUI event loop take over the main thread.

The solution for your problem would be to create a separate thread that will do the printing while you let the qt event loop take over the main thread.

Your thread will be running in the background, doing it's stuff and (since I set it to be daemon) it will stop when the application finishes, or the `running` variable is set to `False`.

```
import sys
import time
import threading

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel('Hello, loop!')
label.show()

running = True #only set to False when user is done with app in the real code.

def worker():
    global running
    while running:
        #I am handling connections here that MUST be in continual while loop
        print("loop")
        time.sleep(0.5)

thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()

qt_app.exec_()
```

But this is a **bad** example since you shouldn't use global mutable variables in thread without locking, etc. etc. etc... But that's all in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: I had thought about using threading as a last resort since i consider it a patch rather than a fix, that is, if there's no other "proper" way to handle it. And don't worry, I don't have globals like this, everything is in classes and set as such, this is just more for structuring purposes.

Comment: There is no other "proper" way since you have to hand over the control over the main python thread to the Qt event loop.

Comment: is there a way to be able to set the code within that event loop at all, or is it pretty much stuck where it's at?

Comment: moving it into the Qt event loop basically.

Comment: All signals are caught in the Qt event loop so you can register a function to a particular signal and then emit a signal which will be caught in the event loop and then your code will be execute in the main thread. But this is a really, really, really broad subject, and without a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish, there is no way I can help you :)